# Как написать запрос на Yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2

У меня есть такой запрос

```
select page, count(*) as c from analitics group by page order by c desc limti 5
```

Как мне выполнить его, используя Yii2? Мучаюсь уже 2 часа, не могу ничего придумать

Comment: а что значит "как выполнить"?

Comment: Вообще по нему гора документации. Нужно просто почитать...

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = new ActiveQuery();
$query->select(['page' => 'page', 'c' => 'count(*)'])
    ->from('analitics')
    ->groupBy('page')
    ->orderBy(['c' => 'desc'])
    ->limit(5)
    ->all();
```

Если используете ActiveRecord модель, то Model::find() возвращает экземпляр ActiveQuery

Answer (score 1):

`yii2` предоставляет разные способы составления запроса и получения информации из БД. Если мучаетесь с `AR`, к примеру, то ничего не мешает использовать [DAO](https://nix-tips.ru/yii2-api-guides/guide-ru-db-dao.html). DAO, по сути, это прямой SQL запрос, т.е. в том виде, в котором вы бы его выполнили в БД. И также поддерживает подготовленные выражения, если необходимы.

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT page, count(*) as c 
                              FROM analitics 
                              GROUP BY page 
                              ORDER BY c DESC
                              LIMIT 5')
             ->queryAll();
```

Кстати, у вас опечатка в слове `limit`